# pass data using value of div (security)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, security, developer-tools

is it safe to send the data(text) of div to the server via ajax? or get the url of an `<a>` tag and use it?

ex.

```
 <div id="get-value">Some Value</div>
 <button id="send" data-url="process.php"></button>
```

javascipt

```
$('#send').click(function() {
     $.ajax({
        url: this.dataset.url,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
           value: $('#get-value').text(),
        }
     });
});
```

What if I edit the text in the div and the data-url of button in the developer tools and click the button after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It *is* safe to do this.**

When working with Javascript and AJAX, you are subject to this inherent problem: *it can always be modified*. The best way to minimize the issue is to make sure that no secure operations occur on the client, and instead let the Javascript do the display and submit.

In this case, you can leave it as it is. As long as you are sanitizing the user input on the server side then you are doing most all you can (aside from obfuscation, which is rarely a good idea in Javascript).

Comment: The URL you are using is _absolutely fine_. As long as your URL does not reveal important information about your directory structure (which yours doesn't) then there is nothing wrong.

Comment: then again, the data-url can be change in the dev-tool, so that means the data will be be sent to the other url?

Comment: It will, but you can also edit the original Javascript using the dev-tool. It doesn't make a notable difference where the URL is located. You are only sending the text from `get-value`, which can also be changed (which should be validated and sanitized on the server).

Comment: The point is that there shouldn't be anything sensitive happening client side, so the user changing the `data-url` or `get-value` would have very few, if any security implications at all.

Comment: I see. So I don't have much choice then. So it's safe but the data would not be properly right. hmmmm, okay thanks.

Comment: @meetmahpuppy if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, and I'm no security expert but this is how I deal with things, you should always validate and sanitise user input on the server side. If a user can submit data, they can tamper with it, so it is not safe until you have cleaned it up and made sure it is safe on the server.

I don't know what you are using for your server side, but most frameworks these days have built in ways of sanitising user input before committing it to, say, a database. I would look into the documentation of your server side language/framework to find out the best way to handle incoming user input safely.

Answer (score 0):

> is it safe to send the data(text) of div to the server via ajax? or get the url of an  tag and use it?

Yes.

Note, however, that since it is coming from the browser, it is *user input* and should be treated as such. You can't assume that data you gave to the browser with the expectation that it would be sent back to the server isn't going to be tampered with.

Don't use such for things like authorisation. You can't trust the browser to tell you if the user is an admin or not. You need to have proper authentication and then do the authorization for the user on the server.

Don't use it without suitable escaping for the purpose. e.g. Don't stick it into SQL without using a bound argument. Don't stick it in HTML without converting special characters to entities (or using a HTML parser with a white list filter to clean out XSS risks).